# Parent child relationship in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a code where i have following data

```
0   a  
1   b  
1   c  
2   d  
2   e  
2   f  
3   g  
3   h  
3   i  
2   j  
3   k  
0   l  
1   m
```

Numbers in the first column is parent ID. So, 'a' is the parent of 'b'& 'c'. Similarly c is the parent of 'd', 'e', 'f'.
'l'  is the parent of 'm'.

I want output in the below format.

```
Parent Child   
a   b  
a   c    
c   d    
c   e    
c   f  
f   g  
f   h  
f   i  
c   j  
j   k  
l   m
```

[image: input output picture]
I need to write this in VBA.
Can someone please guide.

Comment: Can we see what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your example. Why m is not a's child.

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, n As Long

    vDB = Range("a3", Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
            If vDB(i, 1) = vDB(j, 1) - 1 Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 2, 1 To n)
                vR(1, n) = vDB(i, 2)
                vR(2, n) = vDB(j, 2)
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    Range("d3").Resize(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```